# How to make a plugin system using Libpeas for a Python3 Gtk application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plugins, gnome, gnome-3

I'm trying to make an application in Python3 with Gtk and other GNOME technologies. I want to implement a plugin system(preferably libpeas) but it has no documentation for python.

Hence I was translating the [C examples](https://developer.gnome.org/libpeas/stable/), to python. At the point where I have to instantiate PeasExtensionSet.
First tried,

```
pset = Peas.ExtensionSet.new(engine, Peas.Activatable, ["window",window])
pset.connect("extension-added", self.on_extension_added, None)
pset.connect("extension-removed", self.on_extension_removed, None)
```

> Error: Expected GObject.Parameter, but got str

Then tried,

```
param = GObject.Parameter()
param.name = "something"
pset = Peas.ExtensionSet.new(engine, Peas.Activatable, [param])
pset.connect("extension-added", self.on_extension_added, None)
pset.connect("extension-removed", self.on_extension_removed, None)
```

> Warning: can't peek value table for type '' which is not currently referenced.
>   Warning: gvalue.c:188: cannot initialize GValue with type '(null)', this type has no GTypeValueTable implementation
>   Warning: g_value_copy: assertion 'G_IS_VALUE (src_value)' failed

Then tried,
`param.value=window`

> Error: cannot set a structure which has no well-defined ownership transfer rules

Now I got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: libpeas can only extend C projects because it relies upon gobject-introspection.

Comment: gnome-introspection actually provides language bindings for many different languages. Like Gtk for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug and is being tackled [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780685) and [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=660014).

We can make it work with some hacky changes in the API and by doing this on the `extension-added` signal:

```
def on_extension_added(self, set, info, activatable):
    # main difference from how normal libpeas plugin system works
    activatable.set_object(self.public_object)
    activatable.activate()
```